# Compiz / Unity very unstable, crashing very often on 12.04

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm using Acer TimelineX from beginning of using 12.04, Compiz is crashing more than twice daily. Up to today I've been trying to solve this problem by:

1. Using another driver and graphic card.
2. Using newest kernel and Xorg from Quantal backports.
3. Resetting Compiz settings and whole profile.
4. Changing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> button bindings (I've readed that can be related).

What can I do more to resolve this issue?

Comment: what are your computer's specs: cpu, gpu, ram? type `sudo lshw | less`

Comment: Here it is:
http://ge.tt/72zDsjM/v/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had these and other problems in compiz. You can find a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/862430). In short, the solution to that particular bug was to install an alternative, older version of the packages:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:vanvugt/compiz-preproposed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compiz=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-core=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-gnome=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-plugins=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-plugins=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 compiz-plugins-default=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2 libdecoration0=1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
```

Restart compiz:

```
compiz --replace &
```

If that does not work better for you, the packages will be replaced during the next system update. Or just do

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If, however, you have better experience with that older package (that was my case), you can make the change more permanent ("pin" the package at a certain version). For this, install synaptic:

```
apt-get install synaptic
```

Synaptic is an alternate package manager that also allows to pin the packages.

Alternatively, you can run:

```
{ echo compiz hold ; echo compiz-core hold ; echo compiz-plugins hold ; echo compiz-gnome hold ; echo compiz-plugins-default hold ; echo libdecoration0 hold ; } | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but it didn`t help. Compiz keeps crashing...

Comment: Solved by disabling HUD!

Comment: Compiz downgrade also helped in some situations. Now i have stable system at last.